# saving pyspark rdd to hbase raises attribute error

Tags: python, apache-spark, hbase, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to write Spark RDD using Pyspark into Hbase table. The RDD looks like
following using print rdd.take(rdd.count()) command

```
[Decimal('0.39326837'), Decimal('0.03643601'), Decimal('0.06031798'), Decimal('0.08885452')]
```

When i try to write the rdd into Hbase table using the function saveRecord

```
def SaveRecord(tx_fee_rdd):  
    host = 'localhost'  #sys.argv[1]  
    table = 'tx_fee_table'  #needs to be created before hand in hbase shell  
    conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host,
            "hbase.mapred.outputtable": table,
            "mapreduce.outputformat.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat",
            "mapreduce.job.output.key.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
            "mapreduce.job.output.value.class": "org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable"}
    keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringToImmutableBytesWritableConverter"
    valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringListToPutConverter"
    #row key id,id, cfamily=tx_fee_col,column_name = tx_fee, column_value=x 
    datamap = tx_fee_rdd.map(lambda x: ("tx_fee_col","tx_fee",x ) )  
    datamap.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf=conf,keyConverter=keyConv,valueConverter=valueConv)  


tx_fee_rdd.foreach(SaveRecord)
```

I get the following ERROR

```
AttributeError: 'Decimal' object has no attribute 'map'
```

How to deal with this ?

Following @zeros323 suggestions, i am getting the following ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/unix_practice/bcrpc/bitcoin-inspector-webserver/bitcoin/bctxfee_text3.py", line 66, in <module>
    SaveRecord(tx_fee_rdd)
  File "/home/ubuntu/unix_practice/bcrpc/bitcoin-inspector-webserver/bitcoin/bctxfee_text3.py", line 29, in SaveRecord
    datamap.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf=conf,keyConverter=keyConv,valueConverter=valueConv)  
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1348, in saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD element of type [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be used
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$.pythonToPairRDD(SerDeUtil.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.saveAsHadoopDataset(PythonRDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: One should not -ve rep without a valid reason. Neither everyone can speak English perfectly nor express their questions well. Lets be a welcoming community.

Comment: If I may ask, how do you submit this script? Do you need to download an specific jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach` operates on individual records hence receives `Decimal` objects not `RDD`s. You cannot map over these not to mention use `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset` method.

If you want to use `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset` your function should operate directly on a `RDD`:

```
SaveRecord(tx_fee_rdd)
```

Another possible issue is following part:

```
datamap = tx_fee_rdd.map(lambda x: ("tx_fee_col","tx_fee",x ) )
```

`saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset`  expect pairs not triplets. It also may not work with `Decimal` objects. See [`hbase_outputformat.py` example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.5.1/examples/src/main/python/hbase_outputformat.py) for details.

Comment: Link is broken ,could you please check

Answer (score 0):

@zeros, your statement about key,value is correct but not about `foreach`. You can see this [blog](http://cjcroix.blogspot.com/2015/10/pyspark-hbase-and-spark-streaming-save.html)

Here is a working code that writes to HBase

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from jsonrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import json


# Create a local StreamingContext with * working thread and batch interval of 1 second
sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "txcount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 0.5) #0.001 did 9710 blocks in 12 minutes

#function SaveRecord: saves tx_fee for a block to hbase database
def SaveRecord(tx_fee_rdd):  
    host = 'localhost'  #sys.argv[1]  
    table = 'transaction_fee_table' #needs to be created before hand in hbase shell  
    conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host,
            "hbase.mapred.outputtable": table,
            "mapreduce.outputformat.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat",
            "mapreduce.job.output.key.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
            "mapreduce.job.output.value.class": "org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable"}
    keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringToImmutableBytesWritableConverter"
    valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringListToPutConverter"
    #row key id,id, cfamily=tx_fee_col,column_name = tx_fee, column_value=x 
    #datamap = tx_fee_rdd.map(lambda x: ("tx_fee",x) )  
    #( rowkey , [ row key , column family , column name , value ] )
    datamap = tx_fee_rdd.map(lambda x: (str(x[0]),
                            [str(x[0]),"tx_fee_col","tx_fee",str(x[1])])
                            )

    datamap.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf=conf,
                                      keyConverter=keyConv,
                                      valueConverter=valueConv)






lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 8888)
dump_rdd = lines.map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
#print dump_rdd.take(2)
load_rdd = dump_rdd.map(lambda x: json.loads(x)).map(lambda x : x.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore'))
#load_rdd.pprint(2)

#load_rdd.pprint(100)
#tx = load_rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(":")) #this works
split_blk_rdd = load_rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(":"))
#split_blk_rdd.pprint()

tx_fee_rdd = split_blk_rdd.map(lambda x : (x[14][1:7],x[15][1:-15])) #this gets transaction fee
#tx_fee_rdd.pprint(200)     #works
tx_fee_rdd.foreachRDD(SaveRecord)       #function call
#tx_fee_rdd.saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://ec2-52-21-47-235.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/bitcoin/","txt")

######tx_fee_rdd.pprint(1000)

#gen_tx = tx.map(lambda x: x[8])

#gen_tx.pprint(100)
#gen_tx = tx.map(parse_gen_tx)
#print type(tx)
#lst_tx = pprint.pprint(tx)
#print lst_tx
#print lst_tx[8][0]
#print type(lst_tx[8])
#print "here"
#print str(tx[8])[4:-4] #gives tx_id without the enclosing quotes

#print type(lst_tx)

ssc.start()             # Start the computation
#ssc.awaitTermination()  # Wait for the computation to terminate
ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(15000) #13000#time out in 3 hours
#ssc.stop()  # Wait for the computation to terminate
```

Comment: `foreachRDD` is not the same as `foreach`, `DStream` is not a `RDD` and streaming code you've pasted doesn't match neither the code you've shown in the question nor the error messages.

Comment: @zero323, Thanks for your comment. Can you please comment on the difference between foreachRDD and foreach. Also between DStream and RDD? Thanks again.

Comment: Streams are continuous sequences of RDDs used in Spark Streaming. `foreachRDD` executes an action on (surprise ;) on each RDD in the stream and is of type `RDD[T] => Unit`. RDD (resilient distributed dataset) is an unit of parallelism in Spark (not only Streaming). `foreach` is an action on RDD and has type `T => Unit` and executes some action (side effect) on each element of the RDD.